I am trying to install nvm on ubuntu but it showing me an error connection timeout
when I run this command
curl  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
source
it brought an error message
curl: (28) SSL connection timeout

That looks like a bug in the script that you downloaded. Either you mention this to the creator of the script, or you try to debug it, e.g. by inserting commands like echo "debug 1" and echo "debug 2" so you can see where things go wrong.

In other words it is not a Ubuntu issue. Maybe the script was not even made for the unnamed version of Ubuntu you are using. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
